# discord.js | How I can get image from standart discord (unicode) emoji

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690843/get-the-emoji-url-from-a-message-in-discord-js) question: , in my case I need to get the img-url of a standard emoji image, for example:

I tried using `twemoji`, but there is a limit on requests, so this is not an option. Plus, the "`NotSoBot`" bot does an excellent job of doing this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9IIb.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package [emoji-unicode](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/emoji-unicode) allows you to convert an emoji shortcode *:game_die:* to emoji , after you can get its unicode *1F3B2* with [emoji-name-map](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/emoji-name-map).

After you can just find twemoji assets like https://twitter.github.io/twemoji and get the image with the unicode.

```
const getUnicode = require('emoji-unicode'),
      Emojis = require('emoji-name-map');

const emoji = Emojis.get(':game_die:');
const emojiUnicode = getUnicode(emoji);
const emojiUrl = `https://twitter.github.io/twemoji/v/13.1.0/72x72/${emojiUnicode}.png`;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How did you find these assets?

Comment: It's the assets of twitter twemoji repository!